# PHP File upload not working, noting output to browser

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to build an image upload for my site, I have the following only nothing is output at all, yet my page renders okay? Can anybody see where I may be going wrong?\

```
    //if they DID upload a file...
if($_FILES['profile_image']['name'])
{
    //if no errors...
    if(!$_FILES['profile_image']['error'])
    {
        //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
        $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['profile_image']['tmp_name']); //rename file
        if($_FILES['profile_image']['size'] > (1024000)) //can't be larger than 1 MB
        {
            $valid_file = false;
            $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
        }

        //if the file has passed the test
        if($valid_file)
        {
            //move it to where we want it to be
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_image']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$new_file_name);
            $message = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';
        }
    }
    //if there is an error...
    else
    {
        //set that to be the returned message
        $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['profile_image']['error'];
    }
}

else {
echo    'success';
    }
```

---

```
<form method="post" action="./process-signup.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >


    <input type="file" class="profile_image text-input" name="profile_image" placeholder="Upload a picture"/><br />
    <input type="submit" id="signup-com-btn" value="Complete Signup" />

</form>
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML portion of your code?

Comment: start with `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: Array ( [profile_image] => Array ( [name] => 4.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/php5MznP2 [error] => 0 [size] => 119731 ) )

Answer (score 1):

In you PHP script, you have assigned the variable `$message` to different values, on different stages, like this:

```
 $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
 $message = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';   
 $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:
```

but you are **not** actually `echoing` it out, so you are not getting any message.

SO, I would recommend echoing it, obviously.

Comment: I've tried `echo` my messages too @PHPNOOB but still nothing is output

Comment: Well, the problem could be, something to do with `Variable scope` So, just don't assign, the values, and just echo them from inside the script like `echo 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';`